# $C$ closed with nonempty interior $\Rightarrow$ $\operatorname{int}C$ is dense

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let's consider $C$ a closed set in $X$, such that $\operatorname{int}C\neq\emptyset$.

I should prove that $\operatorname{int}C$ is dense".

The book doesn't specify *where* should it be dense, but I think it means 
"$\operatorname{int}C$ is dense in $C$".

How can I prove this?

Mant thanks

Comment: It is meant dense in C.

Comment: Yes, I just have seen that, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false: consider the set $C=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ in the space $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. The interior of $C$ is $(0,1)$, which is not dense in $C$.

Comment: Wow. Genius! How do you come up with examples like this Brian ?

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: Lots of experience: I've been doing topology for almost $50$ years now.